# Value of type Any has no subscripts

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code.

```
func setUserToken(_ user: NSDictionary) {
    self.userId = user["user"]["id"] as! String;
```

I get the error "Value of type Any has no subscripts". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The type of any lookup from a `NSDictionary` is `Any`. You know (or think you know) it is another dictionary, but Swift does not. You must establish the type before you can do the second lookup.

```
func setUserToken(_ user: NSDictionary) {
    if let userDict = user["user"] as? NSDictionary {
        // We now know “user” is a valid key and its value
        // is another NSDictionary
 
        if let userId = userDict["id"] as? String {
            // We now know “id” is a valid key and its
            // value is of type String which has been
            // assigned to userId.  Now assign it to the
            // property
            self.userId = userId
            return
        }
    }

    // If we get here, something went wrong.
    // Assign a reasonable default value.
    self.userId = “user unknown”
}
```

---

You can do it in a single line using optional chaining and the nil coalescing operator:

```
self.userId = ((user["user"] as? NSDictionary)?["id"] as? String) ?? “user unknown”
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your json before parsing it. Try This:

```
func setUserToken(_ user: NSDictionary) {    
    guard let userData = user as? NSDictionary else{return}
    guard let user = userData["user"] as? String else{return}
    self.userid = user["id"] as? String else{return}

}
```